# What's the purpose of typings' --ambient flag?

Tags: typescript

I was going through [Meteor-Angular2](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping) complete tutorial and came up with

> typings install es6-shim --ambient --save

and

> typings install registry:env/meteor --ambient

The tutorial says:

> Note that "es6-shim" for "npm" is not found in the registry now. You need install it with the ambient flag.

So, apparently **--ambient** flag is used to install typing which are in npm registry.

Is that all?
And **what's the difference between using --ambient flag while specifying the actual registry (e.g. registry:env/meteor) and not specifying any register?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the ambient module resolution in typescript. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: @basarat 's book as a very good chapter on it too. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/intro.html